# Trouble with 'az-getmetric

Tags: azure, powershell, metrics, azure-runbook, azure-monitor

## Hello forum members,

I'm having a problem working with the 'automatic' command in Azure. It seems that the command is not recognized as valid and I am having a hard time understanding why.

The code is the following:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

# Grupo de recursos y nombre del App Service Plan
$resourceGroup = "rgtest"
$appServicePlanName = "appserplamtest"

# Define los parámetros para la consulta de métricas
$metricParams = @{
    ResourceId = "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/$appServicePlanName"
    MetricName = "CPU Percentage"
    Aggregation = "Average"
    StartTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)  # Inicio de la consulta, por ejemplo, para la última hora
    EndTime = Get-Date  # Fin de la consulta
}
# Consulta las métricas de CPU para el App Service Plan especificado
$cpuMetrics = Get-AzMetric @metricParams

# Si hay métricas disponibles
if ($cpuMetrics -ne $null) {
    # Calcula el promedio de CPU durante la última hora
    $averageCPU = ($cpuMetrics.Data | Measure-Object -Property Average).Average

    # Puedes mostrar el resultado para fines de depuración
    #Write-Output "Promedio de CPU para $appServicePlanName en el grupo de recursos $resourceGroup: $($averageCPU)%"

    # Aquí puedes agregar la lógica para comparar $averageCPU con tu umbral (por ejemplo, 30%) y tomar acciones en consecuencia
    if ($averageCPU -lt 7) {
        # Cambia el plan de precios, por ejemplo, con Set-AzAppServicePlan
        Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $appServicePlanName -Tier "B2"

        # Agrega registros o notificaciones para rastrear los cambios realizados
        Write-Output "Se cambió el plan de precios para $appServicePlanName en el grupo de recursos $resourceGroup."
    }
}
else {
    Write-Output "No se encontraron métricas de CPU para $appServicePlanName en el grupo de recursos $resourceGroup."
}
```

This is the command that I am trying to use in the last app of the app, the purpose of the script is that when I see that the CPU of the last plan app is below or touches 30% of the CPU in the example time it changes to automatic plan for example from Basic b3 to Basic b2.

In the end I also want it to go up automatically if the CPU percentage metric rises to 85% in the last hour, I move the pricing plan from b2 to b3, but I haven't reached that moment yet, first I need it to work to lower costs.

Comment: What is your exact blocker now. Are you not able to execute the above script successfully? @Georgie

Comment: Hello,

My blocker now is that it does not get any value from the metric and it always gives me the message "no metric found in appsplan in the rg.

Log I have these:

The namespace for all model classes will change from Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.

The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to be independent of modifications to model classes.

[Get-AzMetric] Parameter Deprecation: The DetailOutput parameter will be deprecated in a future-breaking release.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no empty space between CPU and Percentage when retrieving the `CPUPercentage` metric of an App service plan. If the supported metric name is incorrectly entered, the error "No metric found" is shown.

```
$metric=Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/appserviceplanname" -MetricName "CPUPercentage"  -TimeGrain 00:01:00 
$metric.data
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

*Note:* When you try to retrieve metrics, first check to see if they are all coming in the above shown manner, and then use an `if loop` to filter accordingly.